# SharedPreferences not incrementing integer value - Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am wanting to store an int in `SharedPreferences`.  The int represents which level the user is on in my game.  Before the game starts, this code is executed:

```
    int level;

    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("level_SP", 0);
    level = settings.getInt("currentLevel", 0);
    if(level == 0) {
        level++;
    }
    String str = Integer.toString(level);
    title.setText(str);
```

The text that is outputted from `title.setText(str);` is `1`.

For testing purposes, no matter how the user does in the game he passes the level.  After the game is over, this code is executed.

```
public void levels() {

    // do calculations here to see if user passed level.


    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("level_SP", 0);
    int level = settings.getInt("currentLevel", 0);
    int newLevel = level++;

    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("currentLevel", newLevel);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then when the user starts the game again, they should be at level 2.  In the code pasted at the top of this post, this line of code:  `title.setText(str);` should output `2`, but it still is saying `1`.  That tells me that the int I stored in `SharedPreferences` is not incrementing.

My question is, am I "getting" the `SharedPreferences` correctly?  If yes, am I "editting" the `SharedPreferences` correctly?  If not on either one, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thought:  Do the `0` that are scattered throughout my above code mean anything?  Should they be something else?

Comment: `editor.putInt("currentLevel", newLevel);` perhaps?

Comment: The "0" definitely means something. [See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE). It is also the default value when you use `getInt()` in case a value doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
editor.putInt("currentLevel", newLevel);
```

instead.

When you get the new level you're writing it to a different preference than when you read.

Comment: Please see my edit in opening post.  Incorrect output still exists after the edit you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to change this

```
editor.putInt("newLevel", newLevel);
```

to

```
editor.putInt("currentLevel", newLevel);
```

You are creating a new `SharedPreference` instead of editing the exisiting so the `currentLevel` never changes from 1

Comment: Please see my edit in opening post.  Incorrect output still exists after the edit you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
int newLevel = level++;
```

you are using the post-increment operator, which means that this is the same as:

```
int newLevel = level;
level = level + 1;
```

try

```
int newLevel = level + 1;
```